# In CKAN, I am trying to upload a file using java client.But getting error code "400" but not showing any error log

Tags: java, upload, ckan

In CKAN, I am trying to upload a file using java client.But getting error code "400" but not showing any error log. I have done CKAN setup locally on Centos7 system. Please help if any suggestion, thanks :)

```
    protected String MultiPartPost(String path, String data)
        throws CKANException {
    String body = "";
    String CKANrepos = "http://172.21.9.118:5000";
    String CKANapiHeader="X-CKAN-API-Key";
    String CKANapi = "api key";
    //1st part
    String generatedFilename=null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String filename = "test.txt";
    try {
        // create new identifier for every file, use time
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMddHHmmss");
        dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date=dateFormatGmt.format(new Date());
        generatedFilename=date +"/"+filename;
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(this.CKANrepos+ "/api/storage/auth/form/"+generatedFilename);
        getRequest.setHeader(CKANapiHeader, this.CKANapi);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode!=200){
             throw new IllegalStateException("File reservation failed, server responded with code: "+statusCode+
              "\n\nThe message was: "+body);
        }
    }catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    //2nd part
    File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {

        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file,"text/html");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("file", bin);

        reqEntity.addPart("key", new StringBody(generatedFilename));

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(this.CKANrepos+"/storage/upload_handle");
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        postRequest.setHeader(CKANapiHeader, this.CKANapi);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            body += line;
        }
        if(statusCode!=200){
           System.out.println("statusCode ==" +statusCode);
        }
    }catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return body;
}
```

}

Comment: What version of CKAN are you trying to upload this file to? If you're trying a fairly new version of CKAN, you're using the wrong API.

Comment: Yes @Nigel I am using new CKAN version..and the API that i had used was wrong so replace with "api/action/resource_create" API and it worked well..thanks for comment.